# UITextField hide all characters

Tags: ios, passwords, uitextfield

Our customers want a `Textfield` for a Password which is not showing any character while typing.

Is there any Setting in iOS to activate this behaviour or is it possible to hide also the last typed character using the `secureTextEntry` property on a `UITextField`?

Comment: your question is good ,you need  if I type multiple character the cursor not move from start place or else u need to if I type move the cursor at the same time does not show the char, which type u need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set your view controller as delegate for your text field, and add the following method, this will not allow the text field to show that last character:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == self.pinTextField) {
        NSString *currentText = textField.text;
        NSString *newText = [currentText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        textField.text = newText;
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check below image attachement.

When you put uitextfield in your storyboard or xib. then after select that uitextfield & you can see the properties list in your right side of xcode. Now you can see the second image type of propeties in your properties list. Now true check box for secure text entry. when you select it then after you can see the first image type of entries in you app.

[image]

[image]